# currency textbox on wpf c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

i dont know how to make my textbox from string to currency. I already do search on STO, google. but don't understand how to use it.

let's say i have one textbox. 
whenever it run the program, i key in inside the textbox. 
if i key in 1000, i want my textbox automatically change to 1,000.
if i key in 10000, my textbox will looks like 10,000.
but whenever i key in 100, my textbox will still 100.

here is my textbox xaml.

```
<TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,223,0,0" Name="txtPrice" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" PreviewTextInput="txtPrice_PreviewTextInput" />
```

I ever done this before using vb.net, but now i'm using wpf. still new to wpf. 
any idea how to that? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `StringFormat` dependency property to format the way you want the string to be shown on UI. Try this -

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding YourBinding, StringFormat='##,#', 
                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

For more formats refer to this link from msdn - [Custom Numeric Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. i try your solution. but didn't work. :)

Comment: Have you binded the value with some property?

Comment: Also, set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` if you want the text to be convert while entering text itself. See the edited answer.

Comment: ya, lets say i have a int property. public int nValue { get; set; }.. after that, whenever i key in something, i store in nValue. and using your code, i add in to another textbox. here is the xaml code. <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="126,259,0,0" Name="txtTotalPrice" Text="{Binding nValue, StringFormat='##,#', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" IsEnabled="False" />, but still didn't work.

Comment: Strange it works for me though in the sample. Only issue i can think of is `TextBox` Text is not getting binded properly to your property `nValue`. See the output window for any binding error, also try to put the breakpoint on your property setter and see if it gets hit.

Comment: ya, its strange. i also think the same. is the textbox can't bind properly. you create a sample? do you mind to send the sample to my mail? or maybe you can update the answer with the xaml code and the .cs code. thanks.

Comment: Sure can i have your mail id?

Comment: Send, please check your inbox and let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: thanks. i already try to use your code. all i forgot is "datacontext = this".. thats why it didn't work. thanks. I mark your answer as the correct answer. thanks once again. :)

Comment: That's why binding was breaking. Glad it helped.. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Text" Value="{SomeValue, StringFormat=C}" />
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{SomeValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: hi, thakns for your answer. but i'm still confused. where should i put your xaml code? inside my textbox? I adding my xaml at the question. thanks.

Comment: Put Style in the Resource section. See if this helps: http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html