# C# TextBox display dynamically currency format

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, string-formatting, currency

I'm very new in C#
I tried almost evrything by searching all the web for answer, but still can't do it by myself.
My question is about formating textbox

all i want is that when I writing a number in the textbox, the textbox will show this number with decimal and currency symbol.

and because i have 10 textbox that presenting numbers as currency
i understand that i must do binding.

**Sorry for my english.**

here is my class converter

```
class Bindings : IvalueConverter
{
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
            if (value !=null)
            {
              double valueshop = (double)value;
              return string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", valueshop;
            }
     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
           throw new  NotImplementedException();
     }
}
```

this is my xaml

```
<window.Resources>
     <local:Bindings x:Key="ForText"/>
</window.Resources>
<StackPanel Margin="10">
<TextBox Name="MoneyOne" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResources ForText}, Mode=OneWay, Path=valueshop, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat='C'}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I hope somebody can help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

- switch to MaskedTextBox (from Extended WPF Toolkit, available at NuGet) instead of just regular TextBox, component sources are available here: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MaskedTextBox
- implement it as an attached property, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103822/1964969
- shape this example to your needs (creating your own mask-equipped descendant from TextBox) https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1080813/How-To-Implement-a-Mask-for-a-Text-Box-in-W-P-F

Comment: so what you trying to tell me that there is no option to turn regular textbox into currency textbox ( i mean, if you know how acting excel cells. If you want to display numbers as currency there is an option to change it to currency. so when you taping a number and then you exit from the cell . the cell presenting a symbol, decimal and seperator.

Comment: I mean there are at least 3 options. If you want to stick with TextBox class you should take option #2 (attached properties). Other two options are about inheritance.

Comment: hi Yury, I found here similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988729/currency-textbox-on-wpf-c-sharp) , and i saw that @RohitVats answer this question by email. i think i'm didn't bind it correctly.